# In RSpec, how to expect multiple messages with different parameters in any order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

RSpec seems to match messages received by a method in order. I am not sure how to make the following code work:

```
allow(a).to receive(:f)
expect(a).to receive(:f).with(2)
a.f(1)
a.f(2)
a.f(3)
```

The reason I am asking is that some calls of `a.f` are controlled by an upper layer of my code, so I cannot add expectations to these method calls.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What are you trying to accomplish with this test? Can you give some info on what `a` and `f` are and how they're defined?

Answer (score 21):

RSpec spies are a way to test this situation. To spy on a method, stub it with `allow` with no constraints other than the method name, call the method, and `expect` the exact method calls afterwards.

For example:

```
allow(a).to receive(:f)
a.f(2)
a.f(1)
a.f(3)
expect(a).to have_received(:f).exactly(3).times
[1, 2, 3].each do |arg|
  expect(a).to have_received(:f).with(arg)
end
```

As you can see, this way of expecting method calls doesn't impose an order.

Answer (score 1):

Try this as a possible way:

```
expect(a).to receive(:f).at_most(3).times
```

You can find more examples [here](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/setting-constraints/receive-counts)